# MASM ReadFile failed because of a bad handle value in EAX register

Tags: file-io, masm, masm32

I want to convert the following C++ program in MASM (The goal is to open an existing file, write a string into it and at the end read the file) :

```
void __cdecl    _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    HANDLE      hFile;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if ((hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Bloodsucker94\\Desktop\\TestFile.txt"),
                       GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
                       FILE_SHARE_READ,
                       NULL,
                       OPEN_EXISTING,
                       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                       NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        _tprintf(TEXT("CreateFile() failed code %d\n"), GetLastError());

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    char        DataBuffer[1024] = "aaa";
    DWORD       dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(DataBuffer);
    DWORD       dwBytesWritten = 0;

    //_tprintf(TEXT("CreateFile() HFILE=%d\n"), hFile);

    if (WriteFile(hFile, DataBuffer, dwBytesToWrite, &dwBytesWritten, NULL) == FALSE)
        _tprintf(TEXT("WriteFile() failed code %d\n"), GetLastError());

    //_tprintf(TEXT("WriteFile() HFILE=%d\n"), hFile);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);

    char        ReadBuffer[4096] = {0};
    DWORD       dwBytesRead;

    if (FALSE == ReadFile(hFile, ReadBuffer, 4096, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
        _tprintf(TEXT("ReadFile() failed code %d\n"), GetLastError());

    printf("|%s|", ReadBuffer);

    getchar();
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

The ASM code :

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include                         \masm32\include\windows.inc
include                         \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include                         \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib                      \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib                      \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
include                         \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
includelib                      \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

.data

FileName                        BYTE                            "HelloWorld.txt", 0
BufferToWrite                   BYTE                            "Hell yeaahhhhhh!!!!", 0
ErrorCreateMsgFormat            BYTE                            "CreateFile() failed with code %d", 0
ErrorReadMsgFormat              BYTE                            "ReadFile() failed with code %d", 0
ErrorWriteMsgFormat             BYTE                            "WriteFile() failed with code %d", 0
CheckFormat                     BYTE                            "hFile=%d", 0
CheckSize                       BYTE                            "size=%d", 0
CheckPtr                        BYTE                            "EAX_ADDR=Ox%08X", 0
OutputFormat                    BYTE                            "output=%s", 0

.data?

hFile                           HANDLE                          ?
hFileCopy                       HANDLE                          ?
FileSize                        DWORD                           ?
hMem                            LPVOID                          ?
BytesRead                       LPDWORD                         ?
ErrorCode                       DWORD                           ?
RetRead                         BOOL                            ?
RetWrite                        BOOL                            ?
NumberOfBytesToWrite            DWORD                           ?
NumberOfBytesWritten            DWORD                           ?
BufferToWriteSize               DWORD                           ?

.code

start:
    invoke  lstrlen,            ADDR BufferToWrite
    mov     BufferToWriteSize,  eax

    ;-----------------------------CREATE-------------------------------

    invoke  CreateFile,         ADDR FileName,                  \
                                GENERIC_WRITE + GENERIC_READ,   \
                                0,                              \
                                NULL,                           \
                                OPEN_EXISTING,                  \
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,          \
                                NULL

    mov     hFile,              eax

    .IF hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
            invoke              GetLastError
            mov ErrorCode,      eax
            invoke crt_printf,  ADDR ErrorCreateMsgFormat,      \
                                ErrorCode
            jmp                 _quit
    .ENDIF

    invoke  crt_printf,         ADDR CheckFormat,               \
                                hFile


    ;---------------------------WRITE---------------------------------


    invoke  WriteFile,          hFile,                          \
                                ADDR BufferToWrite,             \
                                BufferToWriteSize,              \
                                ADDR NumberOfBytesWritten,      \
                                NULL

    mov     RetWrite,           eax

    .IF RetWrite == FALSE
            invoke              GetLastError
            mov ErrorCode,      eax
            invoke crt_printf,  ADDR ErrorWriteMsgFormat,       \
                                ErrorCode
            jmp                 _quit
    .ENDIF

    invoke  crt_printf,         ADDR CheckFormat,               \
                                hFile

    ;--------------------------READ----------------------------------

    invoke  GetFileSize,        eax,                            \ ;problem start here
                                NULL

    mov     FileSize,           eax
    inc     eax

    invoke  crt_printf,         ADDR CheckSize,                 \
                                FileSize

    invoke  GlobalAlloc,        GMEM_FIXED,                     \
                                eax

    mov     hMem,               eax
    add     eax,                FileSize

    mov     BYTE PTR [eax],     0

    invoke  ReadFile,           hFile,                          \
                                hMem,                           \
                                FileSize,                       \
                                ADDR BytesRead,                 \
                                NULL

    mov     RetRead,            eax

    .IF RetRead == FALSE
            invoke              GetLastError
            mov ErrorCode,      eax
            invoke crt_printf,  ADDR ErrorReadMsgFormat,        \
                                ErrorCode
            jmp                 _quit
    .ENDIF

    invoke  crt_printf,         ADDR CheckFormat,               \
                                hFile

    invoke  crt_printf,         ADDR OutputFormat,              \
                                hMem

    invoke  CloseHandle,        hFile
    invoke  GlobalFree,         hMem

_quit:
    invoke  ExitProcess,        0

end start
```

The problem is EAX register not contain the CreateFile return value (hFile).
It's normal because it contains at the point of the execution the value of the WriteFile function. I didn't find any solution to conserve the initial value of eax returned by CreatefILE function and use it again after the WriteFile function call.
I can't do this :

```
mov     FileSize,           hFile
```

I just want to save the first value of eax. I tried to save it into another register but it does not work. Does anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eiher:

```
.data
savedValue DWORD ?

.code
…
// save to a variable
mov    savedValue, eax
…
// restore from a variable
mov    eax, savedValue
…
```

or:

```
.code
…
// save to stack
push   eax
…
// restore from stack
pop    eax
…
```

Sorry for any syntax errors. It's been a long a time since the last common use case for direct assembly use.

Comment: According to your advice I added the ligne of code : mov eax, hFile to get back the first eax value and it works perfectly ! Thank you very much for your help. Bye!